# Magento 2.3.2: Product View page does not load

Tags: magento2, product-images

The entire product view page does not load and the spinner keeps on loading infinity.

Error on the console:

> The resource from “/pub/media/mgs/fbuilder/css/blocks.min.css” was
>   blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
>   (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). The resource from
>   “/pub/media/mgs/fbuilder/css/blocks.min.css” was blocked due to MIME
>   type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>   nhd-0108bz-fsy-ybw-33v3.html

How can we solve this problem? I am not able to move forward(Add to cart) because of this.

Comment: is there any console errors?

Comment: @Manjunath. Yes.....The resource from “/pub/media/mgs/fbuilder/css/blocks.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).                                                                                  The resource from “/pub/media/mgs/fbuilder/css/blocks.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
nhd-0108bz-fsy-ybw-33v3.html

Comment: Then check where the css file is called and remove its type attribute. And give a try.

Comment: @Manjunath Sorry did not get you. Can u please ellabortae

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused due to the permission issue on the static files.

To fix this issue,

1) Go to file path `pub/static/`

2) Check whether `.htaccess` file is available (hidden file - Press cntrl+H to view it).

3) If not available, based on the Magento version get `.htaccess` file in the file path `pub/static/` and move into your server.

4) Finally, clear your browser and Magento cache and check it.

Let me know if this helpfull. Thanks

Comment: I tried this, but not useful

Comment: Check css file is included properly or not and also remove blocks.min.css from code and redeploy static content and check.

Comment: now i am getting only this error ReferenceError: wishlist is not defined
knockout.js line 2992 > Function:3:57